# How can I fade a div after the page is loaded using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade the Movies div of this HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div id=Movies class="col-md-4">
   <h2>Movies</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>

 </div>
</div>
```

and I'm using this jquery code

```
<script>
    $(function(){$("#Movies").show("slow");
                });
</script>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<script>         
          $(document).ready(function(){$("#Movies").fadeIn(3000);
                             });
</script>
```

But it ain't working. The page loads with no fade in. The div just loads like every other element. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to make it hidden, then only it will `fadeIn` slowly when the page loads

```
#Movies {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that to work; `#movie` has to be hidden, then show when the document is ready as the jQuery function implies.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#movies").fadeIn(3000);
                             
});
```

```css
#movies {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id=movies class="col-md-4">
   <h2>Movies</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to hide the movies div and then fade in. Also i see that your id "Movies" is not withing quotes in the question code snippet. Hope it helps.

Html

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="Movies" class="col-md-4" style="display:none">
   <h2>Movies</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Movies").fadeIn(3000);
});
```